# how to select first child div from div parent

Tags: html, css

I have a movie card where the content is dynamic. I'm trying to select the first child DIV of the `left-side-bar`, however, since the content is dynamically generated, the `background-color` is changed to all divs.

```css
#left-side-bar div:first-child {
  background-color: #e50914 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-side-bar">
  <h3 style="border-bottom: 1px solid red; padding-bottom: 7px">
    Top 5 movies
  </h3>
  @foreach (var movie in Model.SidebarData.TopMovies) {
  <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@movie.Id">
    <div class="card-sb">
      <center><img src="@movie.ImageUrl" /></center>
      <p>@movie.Title</p>
      <span class="crown">
        <i class="fas fa-crown" style="color: goldenrod"></i>
        @movie.Views
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the `h3` to always have the background?

Comment: only the first div(card-sb)

Comment: @MisterJojo He wants to select the first `.card-sb`...

Comment: @MisterJojo There is a loop.. so there will be multiple `a` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:first-child` selector is intended, like the name says, to select the first child of a parent tag.

But in your example there is `a` tag as a parent element on the div. So if you apply `nth-of-type` to it, you will solve your problem. So this example will work as follows.

```
#left-side-bar a:nth-of-type(1) .card-sb {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: It's working now, I forgot that 'a'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#left-side-bar .card-sb:first-child {
  background-color: #e50914 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-side-bar">
  <h3 style="border-bottom: 1px solid red; padding-bottom: 7px">
    Top 5 movies
  </h3>
  @foreach (var movie in Model.SidebarData.TopMovies) {
  <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@movie.Id">
    <div class="card-sb">
      <center><img src="@movie.ImageUrl" /></center>
      <p>@movie.Title</p>
      <span class="crown">
        <i class="fas fa-crown" style="color: goldenrod"></i>
        @movie.Views
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: that was my first attempt, however the background is changed to all divs since its forloop. the solution was :#left-side-bar a:nth-of-type(1) .card-sb as #kucukharf said. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Add an Id to your div, then refer to it to change the attribute of that specific element.

```
 <div class="card-sb" id="CardSb">
```

then refer to it in your style sheet:

```
#CardSb {background-color: #e50914}
```

or try this:

```
/* Selects every first element among any group of siblings */
#left-side-bar a:nth-child(1n) {color: #e50914;}
```

Comment: I believe that is a suggested answer to the problem. It's not like a comment on the given problem.